# Matrix Solver Gives Non-Scriptable Result

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I used scipy.linalg.solve to solve a matrix equation, where X, L, and K are matrices.

```
K = solve(X, L)
```

which returned:

```
K = [1 2 3]
```

Although the values are correct, I was expecting to see the following format:

```
K = [1, 2, 3]
```

that is, with the commmas, but in any case the values are correct in what was returned.

Now I would like to access the individual elements of K, but I can't seem to do it.
If I run

```
type(K)
```

I get "NoneType"

If I run

```
numpy.shape(K)
```

I get "()"

If I run

```
print(K[0])
```

I get "NoneType object is not subscriptable"

How can I access the values of the array?

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Share X and L, please. Note that your L should be a vector. In any case, you should be solving an LP problem. Also, provide your code to give suggestions.

Comment: That `K` displayed without commas is a `numpy` array!  Did you do `K=print(K)`?  That would accunt for the missing commas and the subsequent `None` type.

Comment: Look at how your `X` and `L` display.  `K` is no different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue as follows:

```
X = numpy.linalg.inv(X)
K = numpy.dot(X, L)
print(K)
K = [1 2 3]
type(K)
numpy.ndarray
```

This is really a workaround rather than an answer to my problem with scipy.linalg.solve, but I can move forward with this solution, as K is now a numpy array.  Thanks to everyone for your helpful responses.